# How to insert values into specific blank columns of MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

This code would only update columns:

> UPDATE users set 
>   workexperience='$workexperience',skill='$skill',experience='$experience',sailentFeature
>   ='$sailentFeature',skill1='$skill1',experience1='$experience1'
>
> where user_id='$user_id'

But I want to insert values into balnk columns of MySQL table using a reference column.
Can anyone explain how to use both INSERT and UPDATE at a time?

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because `$_GET` data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.

Comment: Do you want to create a new record, or update an existing record? What do you mean insert values into blank columns?

Comment: Any time you have enumerated columns in your table you can be sure that your design is flawed.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for the advice @tadman But I am using this query in PHP where '$' defines the scope of the variable,I guess! Can you please answer the last part of the question?

Comment: That's exactly why I'm raising this alarm. You should not be putting user data directly in the query, *especially* not in PHP. Use placeholder values. Anything else is very, very risky.

Comment: Can you please answer my question asking for clarification?

Comment: I have a form in which I gave some values which will be inserted into the database table.Then I have this new form in which I got more values to insert in the same table! So basically I want to enter the new values into the same rows which were empty before! @tadman

Comment: If you have a two-stage form, where in stage 1 you collect some values and in stage 2 you collect more then you need to do an `INSERT` for the first and an `UPDATE` for the second. This is two distinct operations, one after the other, with the second keyed to the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` of the first.

Comment: So I should enter null values in the first form for upcoming new values?But how can I do that? @tadman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your form accepts values A, B and C but not D, E and F then you do a query like:

```
INSERT INTO users (A,B,C) VALUES (?,?,?)
```

Then you capture the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` value to know which row identifier was set here, as your `user_id` column should be `AUTO_INCREMENT` for that to work properly.

Then you do an update on the second part:

```
UPDATE users SET D=?,E=?,F=? WHERE user_id=?
```

That fills in the blanks, effectively.

Answer (score 0):

I' m not sure if I fully understand what you want to do. I assume you want to INSERT new record if not exist in your database. At the same time you want to UPDATE existing record if there is changes or empty field.

1. Create a UNIQUE constraint on your unique column maybe in your case is user_id:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE users ADD UNIQUE (user_id)
   ```
2. Use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` feature. Can read more [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

   ```
   INSERT INTO users 
   (col1, col2, col3)
   VALUES
   (?, ?, ?)
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
   col1     = VALUES(var1),
   col2     = VALUES(var2)
   ```